# Reusing Tensorflow session in multiple threads causes crash

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tensorflow, python-multithreading

**Background:**

I have some complex reinforcement learning algorithm that I want to run in multiple threads.

**Problem**

When trying to call `sess.run` in a thread I get the following error message:

`RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().`

**Code reproducing the error:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

import threading

def thread_function(sess, i):
    inn = [1.3, 4.5]
    A = tf.placeholder(dtype=float, shape=(None), name="input")
    P = tf.Print(A, [A])
    Q = tf.add(A, P)
    sess.run(Q, feed_dict={A: inn})

def main(sess):

    thread_list = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(sess, i))
        thread_list.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in thread_list:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sess = tf.Session()
    main(sess)
```

If I run the same code outside a thread it works properly.

Can someone give some insight on how to use Tensorflow sessions properly with python threads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only can the Session be the current thread default, but also the graph.
While you pass in the session and call `run` on it, the default graph will be a different one.

You can ammend your *thread_function* like this to make it work:

```
def thread_function(sess, i):
    with sess.graph.as_default():
        inn = [1.3, 4.5]
        A = tf.placeholder(dtype=float, shape=(None), name="input")
        P = tf.Print(A, [A])
        Q = tf.add(A, P)
        sess.run(Q, feed_dict={A: inn})
```

However, I wouldn't hope for any significant speedup. Python threading isn't what it means in some other languages, only certain operations, like io, would run in parallel. For CPU heavy operations it's not very useful. Multiprocessing can run code truely in parallel, but you wouldn't share the same session.

Comment: Great, thank you! I just found this answer as well and it works. I am not looking for speedup but to use different models for different agents in a single environment.

Answer (score 4):

Extending de1's answer with another resource on github:
[tensorflow/tensorflow#28287 (comment)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287#issuecomment-495168033)

The following resolved tf's multithreading compatibility for me:

```
# on thread 1
session = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
with session.graph.as_default():
    k.backend.set_session(session)
    model = k.models.load_model(filepath)

# on thread 2
with session.graph.as_default():
    k.backend.set_session(session)
    model.predict(x)
```

This keeps both the `Session` and the `Graph` for other threads.
The model is loaded in their "context" (instead of the default ones) and kept for other threads to use.
(By default the model is loaded to the default `Session` and the default `Graph`)
Another plus is that they're kept in the same object - easier to handle.

Comment: Is this also possible without keras API ?

Comment: @Varlor Try changing `k.backend.set_session(session)` to `with session.as_default():`.

Comment: Exists a way to emulate the same process in TF2?